# Warning: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended

Tags: java, mysql

When connecting a MySQL database I get the warning below:

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

please help me out from this problem

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JdbcCreateTable {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/INTtech","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("create table Author(AID int primary key,Aname varchar(20),AContact no int,ACountry string)");
        System.out.println("Table is created"+i);
        con.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 48):

Put the useSSL=false at the end of the name database:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/INTtech?useSSL=false","root","root");
```

Comment: I face the same error , I added useSSL=false in my code but it doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: how did you write the false statement.

Comment: Grlouk, make sure you definitely use the same URL to connect that you configure.

Comment: Is this change okay to go with production setup?

Comment: If the stored data are really private is not recommended. Then is necessary generate a certificate to protect the data.

Comment: Not false, but You will also need to set useSSL to true in your connection parameters for MySQL