# SQL Ant Task: WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended

Tags: mysql, maven-ant-tasks

I'm running an `ant task` doing some SQL on a MySQL-5.7 server and I don't want to use SSL. I'm currently using `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar` to connect to a MySQL-5.7 (`v5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`)

My SQL properties look like this

```
<sql
    url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.box.lan:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false"
    userid="my-user"
    password="xxx"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    onerror="continue"
    showWarnings="false"
    delimiter=";"
    encoding="UTF-8">
```

Unluckily the driver does not seem to care about any combination of `autoReconnect`, `useSSL` and/or `verifyServerCertificate`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689570/warn-establishing-ssl-connection-without-servers-identity-verification-is-not), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224970/warning-establishing-ssl-connection-without-servers-identity-verification-is-n) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database).

Exact error is

> Thu Jun 22 12:20:32 GMT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: Try ending it with a semicolon `url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.box.lan:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false;"`

Comment: @Tschallacka thanks for your input, unluckily this does not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<sql
    url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.box.lan:3306/mydb"
    userid="my-user"
    password="xxx"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    onerror="continue"
    showWarnings="false"
    delimiter=";"    
    encoding="UTF-8">
    <connectionProperty name="useSSL" value="false" />
    <connectionProperty name="verifyServerCertificate" value="false" />
    <connectionProperty name="autoReconnect" value="true" />
</sql>
```

I'm guessing that ant doesn't parse the connection url properties/doesn't use them for connecting. This seems like a "logical" thing to try by using `connectionProperty` to set the individual values

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html